# Why can't I get this json value with Python 3?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I want to parse a JSON value like this:

```
{"1DyRGJQZZMr9LxRFXHq5AZ4gopqk7pCPZi":{"final_balance":772038,"n_tx":4137,"total_received":23382077223}}
```

In order to only keep the value 772038 in `final_balance`, I try this:

```
import json
import urllib.request

# download raw json object
url = "http://blockchain.info/balance?active=1DyRGJQZZMr9LxRFXHq5AZ4gopqk7pCPZi"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()
print(data)

# parse json object
obj = json.loads(data)
print(obj.values())

# output some object attributes
print('$ ' + obj['final_balance'])
```

I have tried a lot of things, but, each time, I get an error like this:

```
> print('$ ' + obj.values()['final_balance']) TypeError: 'dict_values'
> object is not subscriptable (Or Keyerror )
> {"1DyRGJQZZMr9LxRFXHq5AZ4gopqk7pCPZi":{"final_balance":772038,"n_tx":4137,"total_received":23382077223}}
> dict_values([{'final_balance': 772038, 'n_tx': 4137, 'total_received': 23382077223}])
```

Comment: `for k, v in obj.items(): print(k, v['final_balance'])`, assuming the data may contain multiple results…

Comment: PERFECT ! Thank ! Can you explain more about k, v ?

Comment: It's `key: value` pair. In your case, key is `1DyRGJQZZMr9LxRFXHq5AZ4gopqk7pCPZi` and value is `{"final_balance":772038,"n_tx":4137,"total_received":23382077223}`

Answer (score 1):

Your code would work if you wrote:

```
# output some object attributes
print('$ ' + obj["1DyRGJQZZMr9LxRFXHq5AZ4gopqk7pCPZi"]['final_balance'])
```

ie. first you need to access the the dict key, "1DyRGJQZZMr9LxRFXHq5AZ4gopqk7pCPZi" in

```json
{
   "1DyRGJQZZMr9LxRFXHq5AZ4gopqk7pCPZi": {
      "final_balance": 772038,
      "n_tx": 4137,
      "total_received": 23382077223
   }
}
```

to access the value:

```json
{
   "final_balance": 772038,
   "n_tx": 4137,
   "total_received": 23382077223
}
```

deceze's answer works because

```py
for k, v in obj.items():
```

iterates over each "key-value" pair at the root of the json object